# Usage of Multiple annotations on a map view

Tags: ios, mkannotation

Am using multiple annotations in map view ..but all my coding is correct..But 
i have a single error representing

" Property coordinate not found on object of type id"
with the following code

```
NSLog(@"%d",[annotations count]);
    MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id  annotation in annotations) {
        NSLog(@"fly to on");
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotations.coordinate);

        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
            flyTo = pointRect;
        } else {
            flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
        }
    }

    // Position the map so that all overlays and annotations are visible on screen.
    mapView.visibleMapRect = flyTo;
```

But i had seen that i had imported the controller in which this coordinate is defined into this map view controller..Please suggest me the correct code to correct

Comment: did you mean to write annotation.coordinate ? and not annotations.coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you do need to change `annotations` in this line:

```
MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotations.coordinate);
```

to `annotation` (the current object in the array being looped through):

```
MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
```

But you also need to declare the `annotation` object in the `for` loop like this:

```
for (id<MKAnnotation>  annotation in annotations) {
```

so that the compiler knows `annotation` is an object that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol which does have a `coordinate` property.